# download URL works when pasted/entered in browser address bar, but not in href or window.open or Location

Tags: javascript

why download URL works when pasted/entered in browser address bar, but not in href or window.open or Location
if i have a html file with this code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        function clickedButton()
        {
        window.location = 'http://s1.mihandownload.com/2012/Feisal/October/JetBrains_WebStorm_5.0.2_www.MihanDownload.com.rar'
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Login" onClick="clickedButton()"/>
</body>
 </html>
```

and open it by double click my download link work 
but if i load page in localhost or server my link not working

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine in my browser (Chrome). What browser are you using?

Comment: i use Chrome if you run this code by doulbe click its work but if we run this code in web server its not work 
when i copy code into html file and doulbe click on it the url in addres bar change exam" file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/index.html" it 's work fine
but if i run this page in IIS the page not work and download do not start

Answer (score 0):

i use Chrome if you run this code by doulbe click its work but if we run this code in web server its not work when i copy code into html file and doulbe click on it the url in addres bar change exam" file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/index.html" it 's work fine but if i run this page in IIS the page not work and download do not start